# Difference in hours between two dates

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm in doubt about a question that I do in CakePHP. I need to get all the records from my database depending on the difference in hours with a rough date. for instance :

```
$date = 2015-10-15 11:10:59;
```

I need calculate that between `$data['Inscripcion']['date']` and `$date` have four or more hours apart, otherwise should not bring records database. All this in `find->('list', array('conditions => array('date')))`.

but it can not think of me as to include the value of the data within the same query

Comment: in raw sql, `... where hour(timediff(field1, field2)) >= 4`?

Comment: I think the best thing for me would do it with the help of Cake, is this possible?

Comment: This is much much easier to do at mysql level, trust @MarcB

Comment: You need to simply take @MarcB 's answer and make it one of the entries in your `find`'s condition array. I assume that the two values you are trying to compare are within columns in your table, so you don't need to worry about SQL injection. _(So far the answers have all been PHP, which is not what you need. You need to stop the records from getting to your webserver when you make your database request.)_

Comment: In fact, one of the values is not the same table. But you're right, I need before the server responds me.

Comment: Then the answer is even simpler. Take $date and subtract 4 hours from it. Then put in your conditions array: `array('Inscripcion.date <=' => $date)`

Comment: @AgRizzo Thanks men! It was all so easy, thank you very much! if you can put an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but

```
if (abs(strtotime($date) - strtotime($data['Inscripcion']['date'])) > (60 * 60 * 4)) {
  // stuff 
}
```

Edit: Sorry, I'm used to PHP 5.3, see nessuno's answer.

Comment: Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP built-in classes: `DateTime` and `DateInterval`

```
$date  = new DateTime('2015-10-15 11:10:59');
$date2 = new DateTime($data['Inscripcion']['date']);

$diff = $date2->diff($date);

if($diff->h + $diff->days*24 > 4) {
    //do stuff
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this is not possible in consultation cake? I ask only for doubt.

Comment: Looking at CakePHP documentation I only found (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/time.html)(TimeHelper). But it doesn't provide the method you need. Thus, I guess, you have to use php builtin functionalities